# Why does passing functions by value work but not by reference

Tags: c++, function, lambda, pass-by-reference, temporary-objects

Here I have the code

```
void foo(std::function<int(int)> stuff){
   //whatever
}
```

and it is called with

```
auto fct = [](int x){return 0;};

foo(fct);
```

Which works great. However, when I change `foo` to

```
void foo(std::function<int(int)>& stuff){ // only change is that it is passed by reference
   //whatever
}
```

The code doesn't compile. Why is this the case? I know we can just pass the object to a reference parameter directly, we don't need the `&` operator like for pointers. Why can't you pass std::function types by reference?

Comment: The parameters is a `function` type.  The *lambda* will be used to construct a `function` temporary.  The *temporary* can be pass-by-value, or pass-by-const-reference, but **not** pass-by-mutable-reference (because temporaries are not allowed to be mutated in general, to prevent bugs).

Comment: `void foo(int &x);` `foo(42)` fails for a similar reason. `&` only accepts lvalues, and not only a lambda is an rvalue, it's type is also not `std::function`, so the result of converting it to a `std::function` (a temporary) is an rvalue regardless. Lambdas have unnamed types, and `std::function` can store any single callable object, which can be a lambda or a custom class or a function pointer, etc.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat wait then what type is the lambda then?

Comment: Those types have no names. It's a class with an overloaded call operator (`operator()`).

Comment: @khuang A lambda is an anonymous type generated by the compiler itself. A lambda is not a `std::function`, but a `std::function` can refer to and call a lambda.

Comment: @RemyLebeau [`[expr.prim.lambda.closure]/1`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#closure-1) *"unique, unnamed non-union class type"*. I've just tested on GCC, Clang, and MSVC and those names from the errors are rejected if you try to directly use them in code. Even if they worked, that would be a quirk of a specific compiler, not a standard requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to bind a non-constant reference with a temporary object.

You could use a constant reference.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

void foo( const std::function<int(int)> &stuff )
{
   int x = 10;

   std::cout << stuff( x ) << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    auto fct = [](int x){return x * 10;};

    foo(fct);
}
```

The program output is

```
100
```

Without the qualifier const you could write for example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

void foo( std::function<int(int)> &stuff )
{
   int x = 10;

   std::cout << stuff( x ) << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    auto fct = [](int x){return x * 10;};

    std::function<int(int)> f( fct );

    foo(f);
}
```

As for the lambda-expression then according to the C++ 17 Standard (8.1.5.1 Closure types)

> 1 The type of a lambda-expression (which is also the type of the
> closure object) is a unique, unnamed non-union class type, called the
> closure type, whose properties are described below.

Comment: I thought `fct` is an l-value, since it's a lambda assigned to a var?

Comment: @khuang The object of the type std::function that is created is not an lvalue.

Comment: `fct` is an l-value lambda, while the `std::function<int(int)>` generated by it is an r-value temporary.

Comment: I think I've misunderstood lambdas a bit. I thought they were of the type std::function. What type are lambdas then?

Comment: @khuang: You'd can't name their type, but you can use it.  For example `template<typename TLambda> void foo(TLambda& stuff)` will work just fine (and optimize better)

Comment: @khuang _"...The lambda expression is a prvalue expression of unique unnamed non-union non-aggregate class type, known as closure type..."_ see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda

Comment: @khuang From the C++ 14 STandard "3 The type of the lambda-expression (which is also the type of the closure object) is a unique, unnamed nonunion class type — called the closure type — whose properties are described below."